# jQuery val is correct function?

Tags: jquery

The JavaScript in the code below is supposed to set some values in a form equal to the variable selected[] (possible values for selected[i]: true, false;) For sure, the code before has set the proper values for all selected[i] elements.

However, the console shows the error 'productvalid: [object Object]' (instead of a true or false). Am I reading or writing the values in the wrong way? (I read and googled quite a bit about the jquery val() and related functions like prop() and attr() but can figure out what goes wrong. I also used the val() function in another part of code to write a value to an input tag which does work).

Html code (the input type is rep:

```
<input type="hidden" id="productvalid1" name="productvalid[]" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" id="productvalid2" name="productvalid[]" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" id="productvalid3" name="productvalid[]" value="false" />
```

Javascript code:

```
for(var i=0;i<nrofproducts;i++) {
    $("#productvalid"+i).val(selected[i]);
    x = $("#productvalid"+i).val(selected[i]);
    console.log("productvalid: "+x);
}
```

Comment: Where is `selected` set?

Comment: The `Object` being returned is the jQuery collection object. This allows jQuery commands to be daisychained together; e.g. `$("#productvalid"+i).val(selected[i]).addClass("item")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
x = $("#productvalid"+i).val();
```

instead of

```
x = $("#productvalid"+i).val(selected[i]);
```

Comment: thnx all for your comments(!). I obviously didnt ready the jquery manual properly ;-(

Answer (score 2):

To **set** a value, you use `.val(valuehere)`;
To **get** a value, you simply use `.val()` (no arguments).

It's appearing `productvalid: [object Object]` because when setting a value, jquery returns an object.  This will work:

```
$("#productvalid"+i).val(selected[i]); //setting the value
x = $("#productvalid"+i).val(); //getting the value
console.log("productvalid: "+x); //logging on console the value, not the setting object
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val) will tell you, `.val()` (as a getter) returns a string (or number or array), while `.val(val-to-set)` (as a setter) returns a jQuery object.

So in your code, `x` is a jQuery object containing the updated DOM element selected by `$("#productvalid"+i)`. What you wanted was `x = $("#productvalid"+i).val()`, as [KhanhTO pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335956/901048).